# what is the meaning of green color capital U symbol and file highlight in green color in VS code file names and how to remove it?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github

Yesterday or day before yesterday i hosted my first front end project using the github free project hosting service. today, while working on some different project i saw this issue and i  dont know how to solve it to make everything again normal.

[image]

Comment: green means Untracked, but the color differs by theme

Comment: It's not an "issue".

Answer (score 0):

The "U" means Untracked, which basically means it is a file that has not been committed to your repo. It will go away when you commit the file, or if they are not supposed to be committed to the repo you can add them to your .gitignore.